# How to control the width of my table

Tags: tables, longtable, width, column-width, adjustwidth

I want to control the width of my table.
Could I get some ideas to solve this problem?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[b]
\centering
\caption{The results of Human motion recognition [$\%$].}
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\begin{tabular}{lc!{\color{black}\vrule}lc} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c!{\color{black}\vrule}}{Weizmann dataset} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{KTH dataset}              \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Methods} & Accuracy [\%]~               & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Methods} & Accuracy [\%]  \\ 
\arrayrulecolor{black}\hline
Fathi et al. \cite{Fathi2008ActionRB}                & 90.00                        & Schuldt et al. \cite{Schldt2004RecognizingHA}              & 71.70          \\
Ali et al. \cite{Ali2010HumanAR}                  & 94.75                        & Dollar et al. \cite{Dollr2005BehaviorRV}               & 81.20          \\
Bregonzio et al.~ \cite{Bregonzio2012FusingAA}           & 96.66                        & Niebles et al. \cite{Niebles2007UnsupervisedLO}              & 83.30          \\
Seo. et al. \cite{Seo2011ActionRF}                 & 97.50                        & Jhuang et al. \cite{Jhuang2007ABI}               & 91.70          \\
Wang et al. \cite{Wang2009EvaluationOL}                 & 96.70                        & Ji et al. \cite{JiShuiwang20133DCN}                   & 90.20          \\
Arac et al. \cite{Acar2012HumanAR}                 & 97.77                        & Schindler et al. \cite{Schindler2008ActionSH}            & 92.70          \\
Fadwa et al. \cite{AlAzzo2017HumanAR}                & 97.02                        & Arac et al. \cite{Acar2012HumanAR}                 & 95.36          \\
Our best method             & 99.47                        & Our best method             & 99.85          \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: please upload the preamble of your code

Comment: Have you seen this ? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Comment: Do please tell which document class you employ and whether the document is typeset in two-column format. Which fonts are in use, and what's the font size employed in the `table`?

Comment: Yes. It's the two-column format. I want to fix the width for a one-column format. font size is footnotesize.

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

Answer (score 1):

To make the table fit inside the column, I suggest you provide a line break between "Accuracy" and "[%]" in the headers of columns 2 and 4. Incidentally, I think it's not necessary to have a rule go down the middle of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[b]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercol. space
\caption{Results of human motion recognition [\%].}

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lc lc } 
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Weizmann dataset} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{KTH dataset}  \\
\cmidrule{1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}
Methods & Accuracy & Methods & Accuracy  \\ 
& [\%] & & [\%] \\
\midrule
Fathi et al.\ \cite{Fathi2008ActionRB}       & 90.00 & Schuldt et al.\ \cite{Schldt2004RecognizingHA} & 71.70 \\
Ali et al.\ \cite{Ali2010HumanAR}            & 94.75 & Dollar et al.\ \cite{Dollr2005BehaviorRV}      & 81.20 \\
Bregonzio et al.\ \cite{Bregonzio2012FusingAA} & 96.66  & Niebles et al.\ \cite{Niebles2007UnsupervisedLO} & 83.30 \\
Seo et al.\ \cite{Seo2011ActionRF}           & 97.50 & Jhuang et al.\ \cite{Jhuang2007ABI}            & 91.70 \\
Wang et al.\ \cite{Wang2009EvaluationOL}     & 96.70 & Ji et al.\ \cite{JiShuiwang20133DCN}           & 90.20  \\
Arac et al.\ \cite{Acar2012HumanAR}          & 97.77 & Schindler et al.\ \cite{Schindler2008ActionSH} & 92.70 \\
Fadwa et al.\ \cite{AlAzzo2017HumanAR}       & 97.02 & Arac et al.\ \cite{Acar2012HumanAR}            & 95.36 \\
\addlinespace
Our best method & 99.47 & Our best method & 99.85 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-10] % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!